# Applying a function with arguments that could be either Ints or Doubles

Tags: haskell, types

I'm pretty new to Haskell, so I hope this isn't a stupid question. I have this data type:

```
data N = I Int | D Double deriving (Show, Eq)
```

I'm trying to write a function with the signature `(Num a) => (a -> a -> a) -> N -> N -> N` which applies the function to the numbers within the `N`s and returns an N with the result. If the `N`s are both `D`s, it should just apply the function and return a `D`; if one is an `I` and the other is a `D`, it should convert the `Int` in the `I` to a `Double`, apply the function to the two `Double`s, and return a `D`; and if both are `I`s, it should apply the function and return an `I`. Here's the (broken) code I have so far:

```
widen :: N -> N -> (N, N)
widen (I i) d@(D _) = (D (fromIntegral i), d)
widen d@(D _) i@(I _) = widen i d
widen x y = (x, y)

numOp :: (Num a) => (a -> a -> a) -> N -> N -> N
numOp op x y = case widen x y of (D x', D y') -> D $ x' `op` y'
                                 (I x', I y') -> I $ x' `op` y'
```

I get an error on both lines of `numOp`, though. The first one is:

```
Could not deduce (a ~ Double)
from the context (Num a)
  bound by the type signature for
             numOp :: Num a => (a -> a -> a) -> N -> N -> N
  at <line num>
In the second argument of `($)', namely x' `op` y'
In the expression: D $ x' `op` y'
In a case alternative: (D x', D y') -> D $ x' `op` y'
```

And the second:

```
Couldn't match type `Double' with `Int'
Expected type: Int
  Actual type: a
In the second argument of `($), namely x' `op` y'
In the expression: I $ x' `op` y'
In a case alternative: (I x', I y') -> I $ x' `op` y'
```

I'm pretty sure I understand what both errors mean; I think the first one is saying that the information in my type signature isn't enough for GHC to assume that `op` returns a `Double`, which is required by the `D` value constructor, and the second one is saying that since the first line implies that `a` is `Double`, this line can't use a value of type `a` as though it's an `Int`. I don't have any idea where to start looking for the right way to do this, though.

If it helps, the reason I'm trying to get this to work is that I'm following along with the [Write Yourself a Scheme tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours); all the examples in the tutorial (specifically in the [Evaluation section](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours/Evaluation,_Part_1)) only deal with integers, but as an exercise I'd like to add the ability to support both integral and floating point numbers so that e.g. `(+ 1 2.5 2.5)` returns `6.0` and `(+ 1 2 3)` returns `6`. If I'm thinking about this the wrong way or there's an easier way to accomplish it, I'd love to hear suggestions.

Comment: Not a stupid question at all. The issue is a fairly non-obvious one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The signature

```
numOp :: (Num a) => (a -> a -> a) -> N -> N -> N
```

says that `numOp` takes any *monomorphic* function of type `a -> a -> a` for every specific instance of `Num` and two `N`s and from that computes an `N`. So for example, a function of type

```
Complex Float -> Complex Float -> Complex Float
```

or

```
approxRational :: RealFrac a => a -> a -> Rational
```

(specialised to `a = Rational`) would be legitimate first arguments.

What you need is a polymorphic function that can handle all `Num` instances as the first argument, i.e. the rank 2 type

```
numOp :: (forall a. Num a => a -> a -> a) -> N -> N -> N
```

(you need the `RankNTypes` language extension for that).

Comment: If you're only dealing with rank-2 types, as opposed to higher-rank types, you can use `Rank2Types` instead.  This has the advantage that it preserves decidable type inference (which fails for higher-rank types), although I've never seen this come up in practice.

Comment: Would you mind explaining a bit further what you mean by that? I figured preserving decidable type inference would mean that that I could remove the explicit type signature from my `numOp` function and the compiler would successfully infer it if I had the `Rank2Types` language pragma, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @AntalS-Z [The `Rank2Types` extension is being deprecated](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/cabal-devel/2012-October/009158.html). I'm not sure if it will be totally removed or kept around as an alias for `RankNTypes`. While it is being kept around, it won't be rank `<= 2` only, so I prefer to go with the times and use `RankNTypes` everywhere now.